# How to report Silent Crashes in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, firebase-crash-reporting

Our app uses Firebase Crashlytics and Sentry to keep track of all the crashes. We have covered all of our dart code with crash handling but have noticed that in some cases the crashes come from native code, which means that they are not caught by our catchers.

For example, we recently had an issue with one of our images accidentally getting published in very high res causing memory issues and the app to crashed without any reports.

We were to able to know about it and fix it because of feedback from the users and the fact that it was easily reproducible, but we'd rather have some sort of reporting in place for such crashes.

[image: ios crash log]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Crashlytics can pick up those errors too.
Follow all steps on the package setup guide.
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics

quoting the guide

Overriding `FlutterError.onError` with `Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError` will automatically catch all errors that are thrown from within the Flutter framework.
If you want to catch errors that occur in `runZoned`, you can supply `Crashlytics.instance.recordError` to the onError parameter:

```
runZoned<Future<void>>(() async {
    // ...
  }, onError: Crashlytics.instance.recordError);
```

Comment: We are using [catcher](https://github.com/jhomlala/catcher)  which already has these hooks enabled. We still don't get the errors coming from the native code. I think FlutterError.onError works for only errors from the Flutter framework and not from Native code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching NDK crashes? Crashlytics supports it

Comment: I didn't get what you're saying here. Can you clarify more?

Comment: You told that in some cases the crashes come from native code. And I mean that crashlytics plugin supports catching crashes from native code. Read how to enable it in documentation to plugin